# Rails ENV variables shows nil inside database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my `database.yml` config:

```
default: &default
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: db
  pool: 5
```

and my `.env` file:

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test12345
POSTGRES_DB=it
```

When I want to create db via `rake db:create` I'm getting an error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Which means I don't set the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` variable correctly. To check this after running `rails c` I did `ENV['POSTGRES_USER']` which shows me `nil`. Is there anything else I should do to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the dotenv gem? If not then you should add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

Then run `bundle install`

There are alternatives to load ENV vars from a file, but dotenv is pretty widely used and understood